# Can someone install a keylogger on a non-Jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, jailbreak, privacy

I personally myself never had an iPhone all my life except I once owned an iPod touch back in 2012 for a couple of months but I am still a tech savvy person and I know the JailBreak process and Android rooting. But here goes my question and its a very simple one.

Can someone install a Keylogger on an iPhone which is not-Jailbroken and its running in its default factory state regardless if its iPhone 6 or iPhone 12 and regardless of whatever iOS version its running inside it? I personally read some Quora forum questions and many people were denying that iPhone is so secure that no kind of keylogger can be inserted/installed and hidden if that iPhone isn't "JailBroken". They were implying like the following quote from one of the guy replying to the question.

**As long as your iPhone is not rooted you are safe (most likely the case).
The only other way someone can “hack” your iPhone is by going in through iCloud. Just make sure 2 factor authentication is turned on. Maybe change your password too and you’re good to go!
I’ve made keyloggers for Windows/Android/etc.…. it just can’t be done on iPhone without jailbreaking.**

So I want the experts here to confirm if whatever this guy is saying, is true that iPhones are one of the most secure platforms in the world and no one can spy on it by merely installing a 3rd party keylogger app to spy on the owner of that phone unless and except if that iPhone is successfully jailbroken and definitely APPLE itself can see our data which is not a concern for me. My only concern is that no other 3rd person like someone from friends and family, can do a keylogging trick on someone's Locked non-jailbroken iPhone.

Thank you. Awaiting replies.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but only with the Apple ID & password.

This makes it really a parental tool on a child's account rather than a general threat to regular users.

There's a list here of some of the better-known loggers, but most are jailbreak only, the others need AppleID details.
https://janetcpatterson.medium.com/top-10-best-keyloggers-for-ios-771d85b2d330

Comment: But, that article is from late 2017 and its now almost 2021. I've read about some of these software, but the main point is if they do actually work in case of non-JailBroken iPhones????

Comment: You cannot install anything on any non-jailbroken phone without knowing the AppleID & password. Whether any of those apps is any good at its job isn't something we can answer here.

Comment: Requiring an AppleID to install software hasn't changed so why would the "present year" have anything to do with it @AhmedIjaz?

Comment: I get it why you are trying to say about AppleID being the pre-requisite prior to installing any application. But I meant, lets say for example, there is a phone which has a shared AppleID account and one of the person installs some hidden spying application. My main focus is not on the AppleID being the pre-requisite. My main question is that is it possible that someone knowing the AppleID of someone's iPhone, install a keylogger on a non-Jailbroken iPhone? Infact to be specific, is Keylogging easily available for non-Jailbroken iPhones?

Comment: If someone knows your ID & pass, they can do anything. You gave them the keys to the kingdom. It's like giving them your ATM card & PIN.

Comment: @Tetsujin so basically you are implying that there are keyloggers for non-Jailbroken iPhone in the Apple Appstore and they can be easily installed regardless if they are good in their described functions or not is another question.?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I read that article.

Comment: So what part of my answer don't you understand?